# Add coordinates to image for use as map in Leaflet, Shiny and Shinydashboard packages in R

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet, shinydashboard

I am planning to create an interactive map with markers of hospital OHS incidents using Leaflet, Shiny and Shinydashboard along the lines of the following awesome [template for interactive map and histogram](http://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/superzip-example.html)

My problem is that I do not have a coordinate reference system as this is not a geographic object (no lat and long). Also it is in raster form.

How can I make the below floorplan into something with a CRS (coordinate reference system) that can be treated like a map.[image: Ward 2 East]

That is, I want to be able to pan, zoom, add Markers etc.

There appears to be a way to do this using Java however I was hoping to do this in R as I am unfamiliar with Java. See [Coordinates to space map](http://leafletjs.com/examples/crs-simple/crs-simple.html)

Comment: You would need to manually georeference your image using standard GIS software such as QGIS. See e.g. here http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/georeferencing_basics.html

Comment: Is there a way to do this in R?

Comment: Not that I am aware of. It can't be done computationally, but needs to be done manually, therefore it is unlikely that this can be done in R. Especially as you want to have interactivity for this task (zooming in particular).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution using **mapview**:

```
library(raster)
library(png)
library(mapview)

web_img <- "https://i.stack.imgur.com/8aSe9.png"

png <- readPNG(readBin(web_img, "raw", 1e6))

rst_blue <- raster(png[, , 1])
rst_green <- raster(png[, , 2])
rst_red <- raster(png[, , 3])

img <- brick(rst_red, rst_green, rst_blue)

m <- viewRGB(img)

m@map %>% addMarkers(lng = 0.5, lat = 0.5)
```

Note, that coordinates have their origin in the lower left corner of the image (0, 0) and, in this case scale to (0, 1) in the lower right corner and (0.859, 1) in the upper right corner to keep the aspect ration correct. Adding markers within this local coordinate reference system should be easy.

Comment: I am trying to incorporate the map into shiny - have added the lat lon manually.   what comes after the renderLeaflet command "output$mymap <- renderLeaflet({
    leaflet() %>%
      addMarkers(data = points())
  })

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Comment: Apologies that was both cryptic and lazy. I have reposted a detailed question here. The app will be built around the ward visualisations http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38607045/place-non-geographic-mapview-object-into-shiny-app

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
library(raster)
b <- brick("8aSe9.png")
```

That gives you a four layer georeferenced RasterBrick object (RGB+alpha) you can look at with

```
plotRGB(b)
```

Of course the georeference is not relation to any other spatial object, but it seems that this may not matter to you.

If you want a single layer object (a `RasterLayer`) you can take any of the three layers (they are all the same)

```
r <- b[[1]]
```

or directly from the file:

```
r <- raster("8aSe9.png")
```

and then

```
image(r, col=gray(seq(0,1,.1)))
# or  plot(r, col=gray(seq(0,1,.1)), legend=F)
```

Comment: of course you can read and plot non-referenced images, but that would not enable plotting them on a geo-referenced map background (as in **leaflet**) as this would need absolute coordinates, rather than arbitrary table coordinates. Also, what exactly is `8aSe9.png`? Where can we find this?

Comment: It is from a set of hospital floorplans (cropped to look at particular wards). I assume it was created using CAD software by the original drafters way back but were given to me as .pdf files.

Comment: Sorry, I think I misunderstood your intention. I thought you wanted a map background. For a solution without a map background, see my answer below.

Comment: Ideally I would like a map, as the client would like to zoom and in particular use markers as per leaflet. Plotting the PNG and then adding a layer where incidents occur is a fallback.

Comment: Then you would need to georeference. Here's an example of a georeferenced image, just to give you an idea of a possible result. http://robinlovelace.net/pozmap.html